# AWS Sagemaker init 1K+ models "endpoints"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

under the assumptions that the model training itself is very fast, I'm wondering what is the best practice to spin up ~ > 1K models endpoints 
fast as possible.

Thanks for any hint
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are different models (not production variants for testing), you'll need one endpoint per model and thus one SageMaker instance. Probably not the greatest option (cost, time to spin up instances, synchronous calls, API throttling, etc). For now, I'd use another service to deploy, e.g. an ECS cluster.

Could you please tell me a little more about your use case (business problem, framework, model size, etc)? You're not the first one to ask about this capability and your feedback would be very valuable in building the best solution.

Julien (AWS)

Comment: Thanks, I thought this is ugly. The use case is "simple" , let's say we have data for different clients ( up to  100 )  and products (up to 500)  and based on this we'd like to generate linear models, but could be more advanced later. In the first place it isn't  really heavy computational and we like the serverless idea using the endpoints with API Gateway and Lambda. Looking forward for your recommendation.

Comment: As I understood every endpoint is a running and charged instance, right? What about having one customized docker container as described in the docs and injecting all models into it and using the container as one inference engine with a parametrized endpoint. Just an idea?

Comment: Thanks for the details on the use case. I'll pass them on to the SageMaker team.

You're right, each endpoint is a instance.

Your solution could work. Linear models are generally pretty small, so you could pack them into a single container and select the model to invoke with a parameter. That said, you'll have to redeploy the container every time you tweak a model (might not be a problem if you train them all at once anyway). As your models get bigger, container size and RAM usage may become a problem... We do need to build a better way :)

Comment: Appreciate your quick involvement! It would be cool if it is  possible having one
deployment instance  with kind of a model-factory  (N models)  and the possibilty to call a specific model via the endpoint (configuration). I'm working since years with model-factory requirements and I guess this is interesting for many customers.

Comment: The team will definitely look into it :)